# Laptop-friendly alternatives to Unity window-placement shortcuts

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, window-manager

Unity (I'm using Ubuntu Trusty if it matters) has these very handy shortcuts where you can press ctrl+alt+numpad to place a window in one of 8 predetermined positions. For instance, ctrl+alt+7 will place the window in the top left quarter of the screen, resizing it appropriately. ctrl+alt+8 will place the window in the top half of the screen, maximizing horizontally; similarly, ctrl-alt-4 will place it in the left half, maximizing vertically.

This makes it very easy to "tile" windows in a non-overlapping fashion and is a huge time-saver for arranging windows.

Sadly, these shortcuts are almost unusable on compact laptops (i.e. without a numpad, so basically everything under 15" screen size), as they lack a dedicated numpad. Some have an "overlaid" numpad, accessible by some arcane key combination, which makes things very cumbersome as the sequence becomes "enable keypad - place window - disable keypad". Some others simply lack numpad functionality.

Is there a way or alternative shortcut for Unity to use on these systems?  I'm thinking something using the Super key which is already used extensively by Unity, but I couldn't find such feature.

Comment: Why is ctrl+alt+number cumbersome even on laptop without numpad or overlaid numpad? Even with a numpad, wouldn't both hands be required?

Comment: On a laptop without numpad there's *no* way to use these shortcuts ("some others simply lack numpad functionality"). It doesn't work with the numbers in the top row. On a laptop with overlaid numpad, you need four fingers (ctrl+alt+fn+key) so it becomes quite uncomfortable. I'm more interested in my particular laptop which lacks numpad, overlaid or otherwise, and thus can't use this nifty feature at all :(

Comment: How about using Ctrl+Super+qwe,asd,zxc ? the only used one I can see is d to show desktop (I have a QWERTY keyboard)

Comment: @Sneetsher that'd be great :) now how do I tell Unity to use those shortcuts?

Comment: Actually they are Compiz shortcuts, Run `ccsm` > Grid > Binding

Comment: @Sneetsher great! I didn't have ccsm installed,but that works fine. If you turn this into an answer I can happily accept that to give you the extra reputation points.

Comment: On Ubuntu 17.10+ (with Gnome) check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/971767/349837).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Install Compiz Config Setting Manager (`ccsm`):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Look for **Grid** → *Binding* tab
3. Set whatever shortcuts you like. I would suggest <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+`qwe,asd,zxd` which seems good for a Qwerty keyboard.

   The only used one I can see is `d` to show desktop, but you can change it to to some thing else from **Ubuntu Unity Plugin** → *General* tab → Show desktop.

Comment: Thanks! I'm left-handed so I'd prefer something I can handle on the other side of the keyboard (yui,hjk,nm,), but that's minutiae and I can take it from here with your advice. Much appreciated!