# How to remap default unity window placement shortcuts

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, window-placement

I'm using Google Docs quite often, and love the ability to change styles quickly by using
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad</kbd> shortcut.

However, with Unity this system shortcut is already used for Window placement. Is there a way to change this ?

I already had a look at the Keyboard shortcuts system settings, and tried to find something in Compiz config, but with no luck.

That's driving me crazy, I'm so used to this shortcut !

Answer (score 1):

Ho ho, just found the answer thanks to the comments on another thread : [Laptop-friendly alternatives to Unity window-placement shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437361/laptop-friendly-alternatives-to-unity-window-placement-shortcuts?rq=1)

Those shortcuts are related to the "Grid" plugin. You can re-map them or disable the plugin using CompipzConfig Configuration Manager.