# Use Ctrl Alt Num Pad to position Windows on Screen not desktop

Tags: xorg, 17.10

So far I could position any window using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[num-pad-key]</kbd> on the screen. Even with multiple presses I could change the size in the corner/side.

Now with 17.10 on Xorg the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[num-pad-key]</kbd> positions the window on the whole desktop rather than a single screen. That is very useless to me with a 3 screen setup.

Any idea how to make these shortcuts work per screen and that they scale the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question is discussed here:
[How do I restore the Unity 7 Ctrl-Alt-Numpad combination behaviour on Gnome 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947188/how-do-i-restore-the-unity-7-ctrl-alt-numpad-combination-behaviour-on-gnome-3)

Basically, what I have tried from this thread (and that worked) is this:

1. unset the problematical keybindings from gnome:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-n "['disabled']"
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-ne "['disabled']"
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-e "['disabled']"
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-se "['disabled']"
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-s "['disabled']"
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-sw "['disabled']"
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-w "['disabled']"
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-nw "['disabled']"
   ```

with `sw`, `nw`, `ne`, `se` for corners, and `n`, `e`, `s`, `w` for sides.

2. Then I have tried installing the gnome extension called [Put Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/).
   Using this extension options (refresh page if you don't see the option button next to the on/off button), I was able to set the correct keybindings I wanted.
3. If some keybindings still do not work (that was my case for the move-windows-monitor-left/right commands), you can try to install ccsm :

   ```
   sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```

   And set the remaining keybindings under the "Window Management" section, in "Grid".

Comment: That is surprisingly well working but extremly irritating, that I need to do this via such way, thanks

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, simply install the [Put Windows Gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/) through Ubuntu Software Center to restore the window positioning via numpad. No further settings changes are needed.